# Current location on iOS 10 dosen't work

Tags: uiwebview, location, ios9, ios10

I have been working on an iOS app for iOS 9 and I have been using 
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

I updated my device to iOS 10 and it didn't work anymore

is there an update or something to let it work on iOS 10?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Works fine when running with the iOS9.3 simulator, does not work in iOS10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Safari is blocking Geolocation API calls on pages served over insecure connections. In my specific case, my app embeds a website (HTTP) that uses Geolocation API calls and since iOS 10 it does not work anymore. I will update the website to HTTPS and hopefully that will fix the problem.

https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/release-notes/